# If you do not pick up the gold, do you lose it?

Tags: teamfight-tactics

With the Pirates, you get, every round, a chest with 0-4 gold in it.

But if you don't do the action of going to pop the chest and get the gold, do you still get it? Or if you do not move and don't go get the gold, does it just dissapear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested this myself during a game for weekly quests. It seems the chests will pile up on top of each other as I played 5 rounds without collecting a chest and then ran over it after the 5th round and got 13 gold and a fish bone.

The chests will disappear when you travel to another players board but will be added when you travel back to your own.

I am not sure of the number of chests you can stack and if they start despawning after a certain amount but I can say for certain up to 5 works.